Reduce prod build size of Highcharts in Angular

Is there a way to reduce the build size of Highcharts imports in angular ? The bundle is very large, especially considering we don't use highmaps or Highstocks and these modules don't even need to be imported.
Package.json
    "angular-highcharts": "^17.0.0",
    "highcharts": "^11.4.1",

Import inside module (not root module)
import { HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from 'angular-highcharts';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import XRange from 'highcharts/modules/xrange';
import Offline from 'highcharts/modules/offline-exporting';
import Bellcurve from 'highcharts/modules/histogram-bellcurve';
import ExportData from 'highcharts/modules/export-data';

Exporting(Highcharts);
XRange(Highcharts);
Offline(Highcharts);
Bellcurve(Highcharts);
ExportData(Highcharts);
...
    providers: [
    { 
        provide: HIGHCHARTS_MODULES, useFactory: (): any =>
            [
                XRange,
                Offline,
                Bellcurve,
                ExportData
            ]
    }
],

To get my visual analyze of bundle:
ng build --configuration=production --output-hashing=all --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer -p 8889 dist/<project>/stats.json

Is the tree shaking supposed to remove these unused bundles ? Or do I have to use the custom package installation

From Highcharts 11.3 you can use ES6 modules and include only the modules you need. This allows you to do tree shaking.
Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation-with-esm
